# To Click Button Pass Json Data To Other ViewCont``roller Tableview

Tags: ios

I am developing an ios app..Click on button to  Pass The Json Array  To other UiViewController TableView To Show The Data In TableView..In TableView Array Data Pass on NSDictionary and to Use Dictionary Object. Error is  [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: Unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x7b115560']...Thanks In Advance

```
// Button Click 
   BBAuthorDetailViewController *BBAuthorDetail =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BBAuthorDetail"];


        [BBAuthorDetail setSelectionType:BBSelectionAuthorName];
        _serverObj = [[Server alloc]init];

        [_params setObject:_adDetailsObj.authorDetail forKey:@"author"];
        [_serverObj BBAuthorNameWithParams:_params];
     // BBAuthorDetail.data=resultsArray;
    //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [BBAuthorDetail.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
           BBAuthorDetail.data = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           NSLog(@"%@",resultsArray);


    //[BBAuthorDetail setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:BBAuthorDetail animated:YES];

UIViewController Table TO Show Data

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _data.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%li", (long)indexPath.row];
    BBAdsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


 //   AdDetails *_adDetailsObj = (AdDetails *)[_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      // NSDictionary  *dic = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //AdDetails *_adDetailsObj = [[AdDetails alloc]init];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[BBAdsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.row = indexPath.row;
        //[cell setDelegate:self];
    }
  // Error Part 
    NSDictionary *dic = [_data objectAtIndex:0];  
    cell.textLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"post_author"];
    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: "data" is dictionary type and you are trying to get data with index . that was not possible in dictionary .

Comment: Replace this BBAuthorDetail.data = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; TO BBAuthorDetail.data =resultsArray;

Comment: see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1